# ¿Como pasar los datos de un JTable a otro JTable?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, jtable

Perdón, creo que no he formulado bien la pregunta.

Tengo un JTable con 10 equipos, según haga clic sobre algún equipo, quiero que me abra en un nuevo JTable toda la información sobre los jugadores del equipo. Mi problema está que cuando hago un clic sobre el equipo se me abre 10 nuevos JTable (se carga un jugador por JTable). 
¿Alguna idea de cómo lo puedo arreglar?

¡Gracias!

Evento al hacer clic sobre un equipo del JTable:

```
int filaSeleccionada = tabla.getSelectedRow();

    if (filaSeleccionada == 0) {

        for (Jugador jugador : gestor.getEquipo()) {

            if (jugador.getN_equipo().equals("Real Madrid")) {
                VentanaNuevaTabla vtn = new VentanaNuevaTabla(prin, gestor);
                vtn.setVisible(true);
                VentanaNuevaTabla.modeloVTN.addRow(jugador.toArray());
                this.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Ventana Equipo]
[image: Datos del equipo en la nueva tabla]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que dentro de `for` donde recorres la lista de jugadores del equipo creas y muestras la ventana, y por lo tanta para cada jugador mostrarás una nueva. Si sacas las líneas donde creas la ventana y la muestras lo solucionas.

```
int filaSeleccionada = tabla.getSelectedRow();

if (filaSeleccionada == 0) {

    VentanaNuevaTabla vtn = new VentanaNuevaTabla(prin, gestor);

    for (Jugador jugador : gestor.getEquipo()) {
        if (jugador.getN_equipo().equals("Real Madrid")) {
            vtn.modeloVTN.addRow(jugador.toArray());
        }
    }

    vtn.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
}
```